# String replacement in JSTL not happening for a particular string

Tags: jsp, jstl, string-matching

I am pretty new with JSTL, so need your help with something.

I have a string named "specialties", in which I'm checking if a particular string exists, and if it does, I check mark the input corresponding to it, and then replacing it with empty string.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="specialities" value="OB/Gyn" 
<c:if test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(asc_details.specialities, 'OB/Gyn')}">
<c:set var="specialities" value="${fn:replace(specialities,'OB/Gyn','')}"></c:set>
<c:out value="${'checked'}"/></c:if>
/>&nbsp;OB/Gyn

<input type="checkbox" name="specialities" value="Plastic/reconstructive"
<c:if test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(specialities, 'Plastic/reconstructive')}">
<c:set var="specialities" value="${fn:replace(specialities,'Plastic/reconstructive','')}"></c:set>
<c:out value="${'checked'}"/></c:if>
/>&nbsp;Plastic/reconstructive
```

It works great for the first matching string "OB/Gyn" and replaces it with empty string, but it doesn't replace "Plastic/reconstructive" with empty string. I'm not able to figure out why that is happening. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a possible case sensitivity bug here. The `containsIgnoreCase()` test is case insensitive, so it would pass for example "plastic", "Plastic", "PlAsTiC" and "PLASTIC", however the `replace()` is case sensitive and it would replace only "Plastic".

That it failed for you most likely means that the value didn't exactly match the case. Perhaps it's *actually* "Plastic/Reconstructive" or so?

You'd basically need to fix the casing (and replace the `containsIgnoreCase()` by `contains()`), or to perform a case insensitive replacement, however such a function is not available in [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/). You'd most likely need to homegrow one.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance here, I didn't pay attention to the case that much. But the problem here was different and it was my mistake. I was already replacing the keyword "Plastic" somewhere before in the process, so it was not matching "Plastic/reconstructive" as a whole. Sorry to bother you buddy.